# HMR not working for Nginx hosted docker container but only when compilation happens inside another container

Tags: docker, nginx, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I have the following docker-compose.yaml file:

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25.3
    volumes:
      - ./server/nginx/templates/dev.mysite.com:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./workspace/apps/workspace/website/dist:/var/www/dev.mysite.com/website
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

The templates `dev.mysite.com` points to a file like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  root /var/www/dev.mysite.com;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  server_name dev.mysite.com;

  location / {
    alias /var/www/dev.mysite.com/website/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

If I run my Quasar app on my *host* machine, the nginx website reloads using HMR properly (I have the dev server writing files to the `./workspace/apps/workspace/website/dist` location).

However, if I run via a container, like so:

```yaml
  website:
    container_name: website
    image: node:16.18
    command: sh -c "yarn && yarn dev:docker"
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    working_dir: /build-volume/workspace/apps/workspace/website
    volumes:
      - ./:/build-volume
      - ./workspace/apps/workspace/common-app:/build-volume/workspace/apps/node_modules/common-app
    environment:
      BUILD_MODE: dev
      WATCHPACK_POLLING: true
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: true
```

Then I have to manually refresh the browser in order for the changes to take effect.

What is the difference between me running the compile on the host vs running the compile in a container when they're both writing to the same location?

EDIT: Error from Console:
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console that are related to this HMR issue?

Comment: You know what, I didn't even think to check! Looking now ..

Comment: I've added the error from console. That makes sense I guess. If the websock connection isn't working, then it can't trigger HMR I guess. I'm assuming this is a mapping issue between the containers then